# Hibernate/JPA Using parents's identity id on cascade son's id

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, associations

Anyone has been through this using Hibernate / JPA:

In a mapping that does the "many-to-many" with extra fields I do the following assembly:

Father1 -> SonDocument - Since the son has a composite key which is the father's ID + the ID of a Document table.

The problem: The father's id is Identity and I persist the father with a cascade of the children, so at the time of the child's persist it would have to have a "refresh" to get the ID that was just generated in the father. It turns out that this ID is never loaded.

Mapping:

```
public class Pai{

    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pai", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<FilhoDocumento> documentos;
    
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "nome", length = 30, unique = false, nullable = false)
    private String nome;

    public void addDocumento(final Documento) {

                
        getDocumentos().add(new FilhoDocumento(this, d));
    }
}
```

Son's Mapping

```
@Entity
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name = "paiId", column=@Column(name="...")),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "documentoId", column=@Column(name="..."))
})
@IdClass(FilhoDocumentoPK.class)
public class FilhoDocumento implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "impeditivo", nullable = false)
    private boolean impeditivo;

    @Column(name = "obrigatorioMatriculaPeloAluno", nullable = false)
    private boolean obrigatorioMatriculaPeloAluno;

    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idPai", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false) 
    private Pai pai;
    
    @Id
    private Integer paiId;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "IDDocumento", referencedColumnName = "ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Documento documento;

    @Id
    private Integer documentoId;

....
}
```

And the PK's mapping class

```
public class PaiDocumentoMatriculaPK implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "IDPai")
    private Integer paiId;

    @Column(name = "IDDocumento")
    private Integer documentoId;

...
}
```

Running the following test code or Father's id in the SonDocument table is null at the time of Persist execution on the Parent entity. For this idea, a cascade should take the Id that was just included and use it on the child. It is possible?

```
EntityTransaction tx = entityManager.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();
        try {

            Documento rg = new Documento("RG");
            entityManager.persist(rg);
            entityManager.flush();

            Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);

            rg = (Documento) session.bySimpleNaturalId(Documento.class)
                    .load("RG");

            Pai hpjp1 = new Pai();
            hpjp1.setNome("teste");
            hpjp1.addDocumento(rg);
            

            entityManager.persist(hpjp1);

        ...
```

shows the error:

Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'IDPai' cannot be null

---

Changing the way the parent entity was persisting, first recording and getting the ID and then passing the ID and persisting in the child entities, it worked.

Example:

```
            Documento rg = new Documento("RG");
                entityManager.persist(rg);
                entityManager.flush();

                Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);

                rg = (Documento) session.bySimpleNaturalId(Documento.class)
                        .load("RG");

                final Pai hpjp1 = new Pai();
                // hpjp1.setId(1L);

                hpjp1.setNome("teste");
                hpjp1.addDocumento(rg);
                
                
                HashSet<FilhoDocumento > docs = new HashSet<FilhoDocumento >(hpjp1.getDocumentos());
                entityManager.persist(hpjp1);
                entityManager.clear();
                entityManager.flush();
                
                for(FilhoDocumento r : docs) {
                    r.setPai(hpjp1);
                    r.setPaiId(hpjp1.getId());
                    r.setDocumentoId(rg.getId());
                }
                hpjp1.setDocumentos(docs);
                entityManager.merge(hpjp1);
```

thank you all for the tips

Comment: What hibernate version do you use?

Comment: The version is 4.3.0 with Mysql 8

Comment: Consider set paiId within FilhoDocumento constructor

Comment: I gave up trying to record at the time of inclusion of the parent entity.

I record the parent entity and then take the generated ID and pass it to the child Entity that references the Father.

That way it worked